# Why are Google ga cookies not dropping in Ireland / EU but are dropping in US / UK?

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I'm trying to understand how code for EU / Ireland on homewise.co.uk is stopping ga cookies - but cookies are dropping ok in UK/US regions.

We use a 3rd party consent banner so am wondering if that is involved with this geolocation code (see below):

`<script>   if (navigator.geolocation) {     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {       var latitude = position.coords.latitude;       var longitude = position.coords.longitude;       // Do something with the latitude and longitude     });   } </script>`

We've used Firefox in Ireland to check cookies on the site. We've also tried Firefox in US where cookies drop ok. I've checked some code but I can't easily see what is blocking ga cookies when Ireland / EU visitors get to our site homewise.co.uk.